# Flutter notification using real location

Tags: flutter

I am designing and learning and creating a project. I want to send notification to my user using their location when other user of that area in radius of 1-5km make a post in my app. How can i do it in flutter . Is there any way to do so.

I just planning dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you implement the *location* package in flutter and read its documentation and try to implement it in your app yourself. Then, if you have problems with that, feel free to come back and don't be afraid to ask!

https://pub.dev/packages/location

Best of luck with your app!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).